# Decorator with async function

Tags: python, async-await, python-decorators

I am trying to implement a real-time webcam service in python so I am looking to aiortc. Looking at examples on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/ea116d073129a022805b0a0741ae82a68c4cf3ca/examples/server/server.py), I have found a stranger thing and I can't understand how it works.

On `server/server.py` on the examples folder, there is an `async` function with a decorator. The function is never called so I can't understand how the decorator can work.

```py
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    
    .......

    @pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
    async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
        log_info("ICE connection state is %s", pc.iceConnectionState)
        if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
            await pc.close()
            pcs.discard(pc)
```

In this case, the function `on_iceconnectionstatechange` is never called. In which way the `@pc.on` decorator is called?

Comment: The decorator is not called for that function as that function is never called. However, [here](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/search?q=%40pc.on&unscoped_q=%40pc.on) is a list showing other functions decorated with `pc.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RTCPeerConnection` inherits from `AsyncIOEventEmitter` ([link](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/d41624e6884fe4c803bc9c231017b34af14e73be/src/aiortc/rtcpeerconnection.py#L264)) from the [`pyee` module](https://pyee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). `pyee` is an event system module. This `AsyncIOEventEmitter` class is where the `on` decorator method comes from.

The `on_iceconnectionstatechange` function is never directly called, but the decorator registers it as an event listener, so it will be called whenever that event is emmited, for example [here](https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/d41624e6884fe4c803bc9c231017b34af14e73be/src/aiortc/rtcpeerconnection.py#L1069).

Because of how decorators work, the code snippet in the question is roughly equivalent to:

```
decorator = pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")

async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
    log_info("ICE connection state is %s", pc.iceConnectionState)
    if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
        await pc.close()
        pcs.discard(pc)

on_iceconnectionstatechange = decorator(on_iceconnectionstatechange)
```

Here is a snippet of the "definition" of `decorator` (from [here](https://github.com/jfhbrook/pyee/blob/c3244f14a090c5c59867d78dc1bbd7dafb16334d/pyee/_base.py#L58)):

```
def _on(f):
    self._add_event_handler(event, f, f)
    return f
```

Here, the value of `event` is `"iceconnectionstatechange"`, so the code is equivalent to:

```
async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
    log_info("ICE connection state is %s", pc.iceConnectionState)
    if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
        await pc.close()
        pcs.discard(pc)

pc._add_event_handler("iceconnectionstatechange", on_iceconnectionstatechange, on_iceconnectionstatechange)
```

Because the `decorator` function is called, it can register `on_iceconnectionstatechange` in some internal dictionary so that when the relevant event is emitted, it calls it. The decorator registers the event listener without `on_iceconnectionstatechange` ever being directly called, because it registers it at the time that it is created, not waiting for it to be called.

Comment: I am a little bit confused, How decorator can be registered if the function is never called?

Comment: I've added to my answer, @theShadow89

Comment: the decorator is called on the function definition, right?

Comment: Yes. Try running this example: https://pastebin.com/ctRPcApS